# Read file with data python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a file with data like this:

```
{day=20180711,stime_ms=187989.786,p=0.90},
{day=20180711,stime_ms=188004.036,p=0.95},
```

---thousands of such strings

I read this file with python:

```
path="D:\_py\data.lua"
f = open(path)
for line in f.readlines():
    print (line)
f.close()
```

I want to build chart in matplotlib:

x axis - stime_ms

y axis - p

This is easy for me if i have data like this:

```
stime_ms=[187989.786, 188004.036] 
p=[0.90, 0.95]
```

So, how can I get data from file?
Thank you

Comment: Instead of writing your own Lua parser, why don't you just use the [`luaparser`](https://github.com/boolangery/py-lua-parser) module to load your file and retrieve the entries?

Comment: today it is lua file. Tomorrow it will be txt file. Extention doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regular expression module `re` to parse your input.
Something along the  lines:

```
import re

data_re = re.compile(r"stime_ms=(?P<stime_ms>\d+\.\d+').*p=(?P<p>\d+\.\d+)")
stime_ms = []
p = []
with open('data.txt') as f:

    for m in map(data_re.search, f):

        if m:
            stime_ms.append(float(m.group('stime_ms')))
            p.append(float(m.group('p')))
        else:
            # report data parsing error
```